# Yii2- Setting user id to null gives me non-object error

Tags: php, activerecord, null, yii2

I am working on `yii2`. In my project, I am using a module named `SIM Management` in which there is `SIM List`, `SIM Issue` and `SIM Return`. `SIM List` have `issued_to` and `returned_by` fields, which tells the user that which sim was issued and returned back to which user.

Now I want to do is that whenever a `SIM` is issued the `returned_by` field of the main table should be set to null/empty. This step is implemented and working whether a SIM was previously issued or not.

The second thing is when I want to return a SIM the `issued_to` field of the main table should be set to null/empty. This step is implemented but not working.

**SIM Model**

Below I have these two functions

```
 public static function sim_issue_del($id,$historic)
{
    $sims = Sims::find()->where(['id'=>$id,'historic'=>$historic])->one();
    $sims->returned_by = null;
    return $sims->save();
}

public static function updIssueuser($id,$historic)
{
    $sims = Sims::find()->where(['id'=>$id,'historic'=>$historic])->one();
    $sims->issued_to = null;
    return $sims->save();

}
```

Also, I have two more functions which give me the name of the user

```
  public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'issued_to']);
}


public function getUser2()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'returned_by']);
}
```

**SIM Issue Controller**

```
 $m = new SimIssueanceTransaction();
 $m->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
 $m->images = '';
 $m->sim_id = $v;
 $m->issued_by = Yii::$app->user->id;
 $m->issued_at = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
 $m->imsi = Sims::idToims($v);

 Sims::sim_issue_del($v,$m->historic); // this function works properly
```

**SIM Return Controller**

```
 if($m->save())
 {
    Sims::sim_user_return($m->sim_id,$m->return_by);
    Sims::updIssueuser($v,$m->historic);// this functions works but on main sim list view the it gives error
    SimIssueanceTransaction::idTodel($v);
 }
```

The error is

> Trying to get property of non-object (Line 90)

```
 [
            'label' => 'Returned By',
            'value' => function ($d) {
                if(is_object($d->user2))
                    //return $d->user->name;
                    return $d->returned_by == '' ? '' : $d->user->username;// line 90 is this
                return ' - ';
                // return $d->user->name;

            },
            'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'returned_by', \app\models\User::toArrayList(), ['prompt' => "Users", 'class' => 'form-control']),

        ],
```

As I am setting the value `null` for `issue_to` I see no reason that why error is showing at `returned_by`. Also I have checked the DB table. The value of `issued_to` is `NULL` while `returned_by` includes the `user_id`. If I manually enter a user ID in the DB table then no error will be generated.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain that 'issued_to' is allowed to be set to null in your model or that it is allowed to be assigned? You might double check that. Also, in your view you check $d->user2 is set then you use $d->user in your ternary. It's a little confusing and difficult to tell of it is an accident or what you mean to do. Maybe it would be more clear if you renamed your getters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your relation `getUser()`:

```
public function getUser()
{
   return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'issued_to']);
}
```

uses `issue_to` field, if you check `$d->user` before line 90, it will give you `NULL`. Before accessing related model property you have to check if it exists, by:

```
$d->user ? $d->user->username : NULL
```

I don't know what you want exacly to do in this method, because firstly you check `if(is_object($d->user2))`, then you check `$d->returned_by == ''`, and then you use **`$d->user`** - why? To use `$d->user2` you should just use:

```
return $d->user2 ? $d->user2->username : null;
```

Without any others checks, like `is_object()` or `== ''`

Answer (score -1):

#### Model methods need handle,

```
$sims = Sims::find()->where(['id'=>$id,'historic'=>$historic])->one();

if ($sims !== null)　｛
    $sims->returned_by = null;
    return $sims->save();
｝else {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm downvoting this because this was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: you should either correct the answer and add the correct solution to the answer along with pointing out the mistake and then suggesting the solution rather than just adding the code, or delete the answer, I am not downvoting as it discourages newcomers.